# null pointer exception after checking for null pointers

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am getting a null pointer exception despite checking with an if statement first whether the value is null. Here is my code:

```
Collections.sort(taskList,new Comparator<Task>(){ //here is one NPE
        @Override
        public int compare(Item t1,Item t2){
            if((t1.getAssignedString()!=null)&&(t2.getAssignedString()!=null)){ //here is second NPE
            int x=t1.getAssignedString().compareTo(t2.getAssignedString());

            if(x!=0){return x;}
            else{
                Integer x1=(int)(4*(((Task)t1).getAllottedTime()));
                Integer x2=(int)(4*(((Task)t2).getAllottedTime()));
                return x1.compareTo(x2);
            }
            }
            else{System.out.println("null value");
            return 0;}
        }

    });
```

Why is this check not working? Is there a way round this?

Comment: You are checking `t1.getAssignedString()`, but not `t1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking `t1.getAssignedString()` is `null` , you need to check `t1!=null`.

For the case of `t2` also.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing that you need to check if the actual instances are not null, like taskList and the individual Item instances when comparing (t1 and t2).

Answer (score 0):

Before using t1 and t2, you should test whether t1 or t2 must not be null

```
Collections.sort(taskList,new Comparator<Task>(){ //here is one NPE
            @Override
            public int compare(Item t1,Item t2){
                if(t1==null || t2==null){
                  return 0;
                }
                ...
```